# Is there a way to stop the loop repeating more than once when running

Tags: c++, loops, if-statement

I want to build a simple questionnaire program. When i run the code it repeats the statement twice when i want it to run only once and not repeat the cout statements. This only happens when i use strings and not characters. Sorry for the clumsy writing.[enter image description here][1]

The code is below:

```cpp
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

bool N='n';
bool Y='y';
bool YES="yes";
bool NO="no";
int main(){
    char response, response2, response3;
    string response_1, response_2, response_3;


    cout<<"Hello would you like to answer a few questions?"<<endl<<"Please input y or n"<<endl;
    cin>>response;
    {  do{

        if((response_1=="yes")||(response=='y')){
        cout<<"please continue:"<<endl;
        break;}
    else if((response_1=="no")||(response=='n')){
        cout<<"Please exit the program then:"<<endl;
        }
    else{
        cout<<"Wrong input";

    }
}
    while((response_1!="yes")||(response!='y'));
}

    { do{
    cout<<"Question one"<<endl<<"Can birds sing?.....";/*This statement repeats more than once.*/
    cin>>response2;
    if((response_2=="yes")||(response2=='y')){
        cout<<"Correct they do sing"<<endl;
        break;
    }
    else if((response_2=="no")||(response2=='n')){
        cout<<"Do you want to try again?"<<endl;
    }
    else{

}
}
    while((response_2!="yes")||(response2!='y'));
}

  { do{
    cout<<"Question two now"<<endl<<"Are pigs smart?......"<<endl;/*This on also repeats moer than once*/
    cin>>response3;
    if((response_3=="yes")||(response3=='y')){
        cout<<"Yes they are smart"<<endl;
        break;
    }
    else if((response_3=="no")||(response3=='n')){
        cout<<"Do you want to try again?"<<endl;
    }
    else{

    }

}
    while((response_3!="yes")||(response3!='y'));
}

    return 0;
}
```

```
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bTnBY.jpg
```

Comment: Provide the part of code, which ask 'questions', 100% chance you have problem there

Comment: @gimme_danger  let me edit it

Comment: This code is so wrong, you don't even declare variables and don't understand completely difference between string and char usage.

Comment: @SomeName let me paste the whole code  was just experimenting with the strings and characters

Comment: Where do you input response_1 for example ?

Comment: @SomeName it's the first input if the person chooses a string input and not a chat input

Comment: Where do you input response_2 ? You use it in a statement but don't give it a value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You declare `response` as a char, but first time when you are trying to initialize it from console

```
cin>>response;
```

your input contains 3 chars ("yes" in third line of you example [1]), so `response`gets 'y', but 'e' and 's' are also in the input stream now, so this is the reason, why during the next reading from console:

```
cin>>response2;
```

`response2` is initialized with 'e', which causes printing of extra `Can birds sing?.....Question one`, afterwards 'response2' gets 's' and print extra line again.

I recommend you to delete all redundant variables and use only std::string `response`. It will be harder to make a mistake then.

Comment: I understand is there any way to avoid the strings doing that

Comment: Use only `string` type for simplicity. Also note that your current version of program could terminate in an endless loop, if your first entered message was anything except "y****"

Answer (score 1):

You can add a variable that counts how many times the loop has looped

```
int loopCount = 0;
int LoopMaxTries = 1;

while ( loopCount < LoopMaxTries /* and possibly other stuff */ ) {

    // at the end of the loop
    loopCount++;
}
```